# Data Factory Power Query DFExecutorUserError UnsafeProjection$

Tags: azure-data-factory

I my Azure Data Factory (v2) pipeline job has started failing on all my powerquery steps. This was working and I can't identify any changes. Appears to be a spark error of UnsafeProjection$ :

```
Operation on target ######## failed: 
    {"StatusCode":"DFExecutorUserError",
    "Message":"Job failed due to reason: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeProjection$.create(Lscala/collection/Seq;Lscala/collection/Seq;Z)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/UnsafeProjection;",
        "Details":"org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeProjection$.create(Lscala/collection/Seq;Lscala/collection/Seq;Z)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/UnsafeProjection;"}
```

The step(s) **Source** shares a **Sink** with the previous copy step. Previsue step copies data into DataLake Gen2 `enter code here`container.

Double checked schemas etc but cant find any issues.

Hopefully someone can help?

Comment: Just to add I suspect something has changed with azure, powerquery,spark. Created a new pipeline, one step on powerquery. New source and new sink. Now if any steps in the query change a column data type, then we get the error. If only there was a way to get MS attention :-)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this has fixed itself :-)

Put aside some time today to do some more investigation, went into my clean test project and it worked. Then went back into the production pipeline and it also worked.

Must have been an issue azure side.

Just wish there was a way to report issues to microsoft and at least get confirmation that issues have been noticed and are being worked on !!!!